# Create Facebook Event for group page using a SQL database and post using graph api

Tags: php, sql, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have been trying to post to an event that has already been created in a mySQL database and use facebook's graph api to post it to a group page. I am able to post an array created right in the code, but I would like to post an array that I am pulling in from a POST command. Here is what I have.

```
public function get_event()
{
    require_once 'application/php-sdk/facebook.php';

    $config = array(
        'appId' => '1407968509465242',
        'secret' => '***********************',
        'cookie' => false,
        'fileUpload' => true 
    );

            $id = $_POST['eventsDrp'];
            $this->load->model('mdl_facebook_event');
            $output = $this->mdl_facebook_event->get_event($id);
            print_r ($output);


    $facebook = new Facebook($config);         
    // Set the current access token to be a long-lived token.
    $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

        $page_id = '594922100555123';

        $page_access_token = '*******************';

        // Declare the variables we'll use to demonstrate
        // the new event-management APIs
        $event_id = 0;
        $event_name = "New Event API Test Event";
        $event_start = '2012-04-24T22:01:00+0000';
        $event_privacy = "SECRET"; // We'll make it secret so we don't annoy folks.

        // We'll create an event in this example.
        // We'll need create_event permission for this.
        $params = array(
          'name' => $event_name,
          'start_time' => $event_start,
          'privacy_type' => $event_privacy,
          'access_token' => $page_access_token,
          'page_id' => $page_id //where $page_id is the ID of the page you are managing
        );

        // Create an event
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api("/$page_id/events", 'POST', $output);
        if(isset($ret_obj['id'])) {
          // Success
          $event_id = $ret_obj['id'];
          echo ('Event ID: ' . $event_id);
        } else {
          echo ("Couldn't create event.");
        }

        // Convenience method to print simple pre-formatted text.
        function printMsg($msg) {
           echo "<pre>$msg</pre>";
        }
```

I am trying to post the array from `$output`. I have tried to post from `$params` and everything works fine. When I try and post from $output I get Fatal error:

> Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid token: "594922100555123". An ID has already been specified.

Comment: your question is very mis-leading. How can an event be made in SQL? And what's group page- do you mean the group or the page? The event is created in page or a group; and by whom? `post an array`- pls clear what's that array? And the error is beacause you cant supply the id two times. MAy be you can explain your question a bit clearly and I can help you.

Comment: I have a SQL database that is populated with events I have made. I want to post one to Facebook by selecting one from the database.

Comment: Those events are created in a group? And what do you want to post? You're still not clear, how could one help you out? Pls understand